# How to Create a Light Wallet and Light Bitcoin Node, and run it on Mobile?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, mobile

For example, instead of using my laptop to run bitcoind...how can I run bitcoind on a smartphone to create a light bitcoin wallet?

I understand hashing may drain battery, but is this possible? If so how?

I read somewhere a client is considered "light" if it doesn't download the whole blockchain, but just communicates by sending headers.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no mobile apps that do hashing (i.e. bitcoin mining); this would be absurdly inefficient.  But there is no technical obstruction to writing such an app if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to mine on your phone, it's literally useless. The hashing power on these devices is so low that you'd probably need a very large amount of phones (around the thousands) to reach the hashing power of a single ASIC machine.

Also, storage is an issue because a Bitcoin node needs all of the blockchain data (around 17gb as of today), so you'd need a high-end phone that has a large amount of disk space.